# initialize an array of non trivialy constructible objects

Tags: arrays, c++11, constructor, reference

I have a class `Foo` that operates that need a reference to be built (it will be used to work on that memory space)

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo(T& value) : _value(value) {}
    ...
  private:
    T& _value;
};
```

I also have a linear memory space of multiple instances of `T`

```
std::array<T, SIZE> buffer;
```

What I'd like to build is an array of object of type `Foo` which maps the differents instances of my buffer. Which means each instance of `Foo` has to be built using the correct reference.

```
std::array<Foo<T>, SIZE> operators;
```

Still, `operators` is cannot be trivially initialize, and I can manage to build it by 'mapping' the buffer through the 'Foo' constructor.

Is there any way to do ? I tried using `std::forward` and `std::initializer_list` but those cannot be constructed from my buffer.

Note that I need my buffer to stay aligned for communication purposes, and I will en up overloading the `Foo` class to implement different behaviour for different elements of my array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::array` must know on initialization how to construct the references. Prefer using a pointer like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo() { } // used by std::array to create Foo<T>
    Foo(T& value) : _value(&value) {}
    operator T&() { return *_value; } // never call this on uninitialised objects
  private:
    T* _value = nullptr;
};
```

What you can do is to create a static object to pre-initialze your reference.

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
  static T _default; // default-object used to initialize the reference
  public:
    Foo() { } // used by std::array to create Foo<T>
    Foo(T& value) : _value(value) {}

    T& _value = _default;
};

int a = 0;
std::array<Foo<int>, 10> arr;
arr[0]._value = a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to directly initialize the `operators` array.

The only solution I can think of is to make `Foo` default constructible, and then loop over `buffer` (using a loop or e.g. `std::transform`) and "initialize" each entry in `operators` using assignment.

Something like

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void initialize_operators(const std::array<T, N>& buff,
                          std::array<Foo<T>, N>& ops)
{
    std::transform(std::begin(buf), std::end(buff), std::begin(ops),
                   [](const T& t) { return Foo<T>(t); });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to spell out the initializer elements:

```
T a, b;

std::array<Foo<T>, 5> a = { {
    Foo<T>(a), Foo<T>(b), Foo<T>(a), Foo<T>(b), Foo<T>(a) } };
```

Another way would be to separate storage from object construction and manage the array element lifetimes manually.

Comment: @Amxx: Can you update your question to include a specific desired use case?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to use the indices trick to build your array:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Foo {
    public:
        Foo(T& value) : _value(value) {}
        ...
    private:
        T& _value;
};

// Typical varadic indices builder
template<size_t... Is> struct Indices { };

template <size_t count,size_t... Is>
struct BuildIndices : BuildIndices<count-1,count-1,Is...> { };

template<size_t... Is>
struct BuildIndices<0,Is...> : Indices<Is...> { };


// Helper function
template <typename T,size_t... Is>
static std::array<Foo<T>,sizeof...(Is)>
    make_foo_array_with_indices(
            std::array<T,sizeof...(Is)> &values,
            Indices<Is...>
            )
{
    return {{values[Is]...}};
}

template <typename T,size_t count>
static std::array<Foo<T>,count>
    make_foo_array(std::array<T,count> &values)
{
    return make_foo_array_with_indices(values,BuildIndices<count>());
}


int main()
{
    std::array<int,4> buffer = {3,1,4,1};
    std::array<Foo<int>,4> operators = make_foo_array(buffer);
}
```